# Training an InceptionV3 network not working (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, imagenet

I have installed Tensorflow, bazel both latest version.

To train a model from scratch I have to run the following command on this link https://github.com/tensorflow/models:

```
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train --num_gpus=1 --batch_size=32 --train_dir=/tmp/imagenet_train --data_dir=/tmp/imagenet_data
```

It gives an error

```
bazel-bin/inception/image_train: No such file or directory
```

bazel-bin seems to be file and not a directory.

Further, if try to go to /models/inception/inception path 
and try to run the imagenet_train.py file it throws an error:

```
command not found error
```

I have no idea why isn't it working. I have followed each and every step. This is bugging me for a long time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original answer:

> You have to build `imagenet_train` first, what is the output when you run `bazel build //inception:imagenet_train`?
>
> `bazel-bin` is a symbolic link to a directory.

Based on your comment below (`~/models#`), it looks like you're running Bazel in the wrong directory.  You have to `cd` to the [`inception/`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) directory before running `bazel`:

```
cd inception
/opt/DL/bazel/bin/bazel build //inception:imagenet_train
```

Tensorflow chose a very odd project structure: `models/` is a project, but every subdirectory of `models` is also its own project.  I'm not sure why they did this, but you have to build the subprojects (like `inception`) in their own directories, not the top-level directory.

`//inception:imagenet_train` is called a *target*.  Everything before the `:` tells you where the target is defined (the BUILD file in the [inception/](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception/inception) directory).  Tensorflow made this even more confusing by putting everything in a subdirectory named the same way as its project (e.g., this target is defined in `~/models/inception/inception/BUILD`).

`imagenet_train` is the identifier for the target, you can see its definition [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/BUILD#L94).

See Bazel's [Getting Started](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/getting-started.html) docs for a more detailed explanation of what a target is.

Comment: I ran the following command
`(tensorflow) root@opai5:~/models# /opt/DL/bazel/bin/bazel build //inception:imagenet_train` and got an error : `ERROR: no such package 'inception': BUILD file not found on package path.` 

@kristina
Yes, I know bazel-bin is a symbolic link to a directory, but it some how does not work.

Could tell me what does **//inception:imagenet_train** mean?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. I was trying to build it from the wrong directory.